# java How to set vertical gradientpaint for heat/temp

Tags: java, gradient

Hi I am trying to fill a rectangle (300,30) with temperature.

Like either of the vertical bars below.

I am trying:

```
GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0, 0, 
                      Color.RED, 0, 300, Color.YELLOW, true);
```

I do not understand the Point1 to Point2 parts in the documentation.

What are these points? How do I find them for say filling a rectangle or GradientPainting the background of a Panel?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code looks correct, what problem are you having?

Answer (score 2):

Gradient paint works using 2 points and their respective colors. It works exactly the same way the gradient tool in Inkscape for instance.

Let´s say those points are A and B. Now imagine a line from A to B. Points of this line will have colors ranging from the color of A until the color of B. They range linearly, by the way.

If A is black (0,0,0) and B is white (255, 255, 255), then a point half way from A to B will have its color (127, 127, 127), since 127 = (0 + 255)/2 (integer).

Points before A and after B will have the colors of A and B respectively. See the diagram:

```
( color of A )(color between A and B)( color of B)
-------------A-----------------------B------------
```

Now what about the colors of all other points on the plane? Say D is not on the line from A to B. First you need to find the projection of D on the line from A to B. Say the projection is the point E. If E is between A and B, the color of D will be the color of E using linear range.

This is how it works. Now, it seems you need to do something way more complex than that. You will need to create your own way to calculate the color of each pixel. Standard Java2D cannot help you with that.

Maybe your confusion comes from the fact that A and B are not unique. It is hard to explain in words, but I will try. The confusion is because we do not really need two points to define a gradient. We could simply give the gradient origin (point A), an angle, and a length until the color changes to the second color. Think of a distance vector applied to the point A. But let's not think in abstract terms, or how things could be. Let's simply solve your problem.

Gradient paint in Java2D works as the linear pain in Inkscape: http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-tip-how-to-create-gradient-fills-and-on-stroke-in-inkscape/

Look at this image: [image]

The little square is A and the little rectangle is B. Now what happens if I move both A and B upwards by the same distance? Let's call these new points A' and B'. A' and B' will still define a horizontal line. The gradient will be exactly the same. This is what I mean when I said that the solution is not unique. In fact, there is an infinite number of points that will give you the same gradient (sure, in practice the number is limited by the number of pixels on screen).

Then the question probably is: how to chose A and B? The answer is: whatever is more convenient for you. A little cookbook just to make the concept clear:

- vertical gradient: A = (x, y); B = (x, y + deltaY). Where deltaY is the height of the region in which the colors change. Whatever y, the gradient will be the same.
- horizontal gradient: A = (x, y); B = (x + deltaX, y). Where deltaX is the width of the region in which the colors change. Whatever y, the gradient will be the same.
- diagonal gradient, 45 degree: A = (x, y); B = (x + delta, y + delta). Where delta is the side of the square whose diagonal is the line in which colors change.

On the last item above, both x and y are important, but still not unique. The same gradient can be obtained if you make the following transformation: A = (x + noise, y - noise); B = (x + delta + noise, y + delta - noise), where noise is any integer.

Let me know if the explanation is still not clear so I can try again.

Comment: Thanks you for this full answer. My main confusion is however: what are the points A & B? If I want to GraientPaint a rectangle what A & B do I use? Or, if I want to GradentPaint a Panel, again what "points" do I use. This is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Just added more things to my answer. Let me know if the explanation is clear now.

Comment: "The convention for the coordinate system in Java (and in most computer systems) is that the top-left of the screen is the origin. We measure in pixels, of course and the x-axis is horizontal from top-left going right. The y-axis starts from top-left going down vertically. " http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse331/11wi/sections/section8.html

Comment: Yes, that is right. This is the convention since the beginning of times. At least as far as I remember plotting dots on the screen. But I think the question is not "given a point (x, y), where is the point on screen". I think the question is about the role of those points when we are defining gradients. The main difficulty is, as I stated, that those points are not uniquely defined. To be honest, I think using an angle would make more sense, geometrically. But we also need to take into account the practical aspect.

Comment: @Akira - thank you for the extra info. Are you saying that I need to know the co-ords of TL and BR of my "shape" inorder to create this gradient? Are these points absolute screen co-ords? So if I want to fill a rect with is w=300,h=200. I actually have to know where it will start plotting on the screen?

Comment: Yes, in the specific case of shapes (gradients are for any Graphics2D, not only the ones you obtained from shapes), you need to know the dimensions of the shape if you want the gradient to depend on these dimensions. You can also make the gradient ignore shape dimensions. Its up to you. As for the origin (0, 0), usually you do not need to worry about it. The origin will be the left upper corner of the shape, never the screen origin.

Comment: Sorry for asking you that, but if you think my answer correctly addresses your question, could you accept it?